# Get User Ids for DeepKT Sequences for get user predictions

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I working on [keras implementation DKT](https://github.com/lccasagrande/Deep-Knowledge-Tracing/blob/master/deepkt/data_util.py)

I trained my model and need to get user_id of each sequence, so I get one-to-one prediction for each user.

```
MASK_VALUE = -1.  # The masking value cannot be zero.


def load_dataset(fn, batch_size=32, shuffle=True):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn)

    if "skill_id" not in df.columns:
        raise KeyError(f"The column 'skill_id' was not found on {fn}")
    if "correct" not in df.columns:
        raise KeyError(f"The column 'correct' was not found on {fn}")
    if "user_id" not in df.columns:
        raise KeyError(f"The column 'user_id' was not found on {fn}")

    if not (df['correct'].isin([0, 1])).all():
        raise KeyError(f"The values of the column 'correct' must be 0 or 1.")

    # Step 1.1 - Remove questions without skill
    df.dropna(subset=['skill_id'], inplace=True)

    # Step 1.2 - Remove users with a single answer
    df = df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda q: len(q) > 1).copy()

    # Step 2 - Enumerate skill id
    df['skill'], _ = pd.factorize(df['skill_id'], sort=True)

    # Step 3 - Cross skill id with answer to form a synthetic feature
    df['skill_with_answer'] = df['skill'] * 2 + df['correct']

    # Step 4 - Convert to a sequence per user id and shift features 1 timestep
    seq = df.groupby('user_id').apply(
        lambda r: (
            r['skill_with_answer'].values[:-1],
            r['skill'].values[1:],
            r['correct'].values[1:],
        )
    )
    nb_users = len(seq)

    # Step 5 - Get Tensorflow Dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator=lambda: seq,
        output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.float32)
    )

    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=nb_users)

    # Step 6 - Encode categorical features and merge skills with labels to compute target loss.
    # More info: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32142
    features_depth = df['skill_with_answer'].max() + 1
    skill_depth = df['skill'].max() + 1

    dataset = dataset.map(
        lambda feat, skill, label: (
            tf.one_hot(feat, depth=features_depth),
            tf.concat(
                values=[
                    tf.one_hot(skill, depth=skill_depth),
                    tf.expand_dims(label, -1)
                ],
                axis=-1
            )
        )
    )

    # Step 7 - Pad sequences per batch
    dataset = dataset.padded_batch(
        batch_size=batch_size,
        padding_values=(MASK_VALUE, MASK_VALUE),
        padded_shapes=([None, None], [None, None]),
        drop_remainder=True
    )

    length = nb_users // batch_size
    return dataset, length, features_depth,
```

I try to get user from `seq` variable using like that

```
user_ids = seq.index.tolist()
```

but I get more users than sequence from predictions here

If I have 100 users then I get only 95 predictions.

Another approach that I use to get single user sequence and single user id and try to predict single user sequence

```
seq.loc[seq.index == user_id]
```

but I get following error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.float32), but the yielded element was [ 10 120]. Traceback (most recent call last): ... TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.float32), but the yielded element was [ 10 120]. [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_3099]
```

I need to basically write API to predict each user data using this model but try to failed user-sequence mapping.